# Change author information of multiple commits

Tags: git

If I have 200 commits that I have pushed with wrong author information in `git config --global user.email` and `git config --global user.name`. How can I change these commits afterwards in a command without having to go through every one of each?

All commits are of the same author and some commits are between with a different author. So is it possible to iterate over each commit FROM and TO commits and send a `git push --force-with-lease` command to update all of these in the history of the master branch?

Any idea?

Comment: Are they in a straight line?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/750172/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+change+author+multiple+commits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are in a straight line, you could pull it off with a little bit of bash-fu:

```
git checkout first-commit-to-adjust~ # careful with the pig-tail... it has to be there
git log --pretty=%h --reverse HEAD..last-one-to-adjust | while read commit; do
    git cherry-pick $commit
    # here we need a check for the author name
    if [ "$( git show --summary --pretty=%an --quiet )" == "misnamed fulanito de tal" ]; then
        # yep, it's me
        git commit --amend --no-edit --reset-author
    fi
done
```

If you want to only set author name/email (not modifying author date), I think you will have to set values for `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` and `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` environment variables and then issue the `git commit --amend --no-edit` command. Concept does not change.... and if you want to control more things, then there are more environment variables at your disposal to play with. Check `git help commit`.

Comment: `--reset-author` also sets the current timestamp as the author date

Comment: Then it's just about playing with environment variables.... concept is the same.

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify, `last-one-to-adjust` should it expect a number?

Comment: it's the ID of the first commit you want to adjust.

Comment: @eftshift0 It worked fine, just one thing now. How can I push these changes to origin of the master branch. Now it's currently in a detached mode.

Comment: You can set the local branch like this: `git branch -f the-local-branch; git checkout the-local-branch`. Then you can force-push it where you need it

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! You got your answer as the accepted one.